# Find out the initial width when the document is ready (NOT the current width)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div and its initial position is '**relative**'.
and i used **width: 33%**; for its width with regard to the **parent div**.

After clicking a button, it's position will become '**fixed**'

I found out that the width will expand so that it is now taking the **33% of the document width**.

Is there a way to prevent that from happening? I still want its width to **maintain the 33% of its parent div** upon clicking the button.

I am struggling to find out a jquery script that allows me to "memorize" its initial width when the document is ready. But so far the .width() is not applicable because it varies all the time.

Comment: Why don't you store the width of div in a variable and assign the same width to it in the click event callback? Or you can store the width of parent div and assign it's 33% or 1/3 to it.
Also, it would be better if you can show some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't have to get its width, get its parent width, as I understood parent width will not change, get its width and divide it to 3. that will be what you want

Comment: Yes. Actually I just find that out.